# Oracle Performance issue on where clause filter predicates

Tags: oracle, performance, join, indexing, self

New to performance improvements and am struggling with the following. Following table is used to keep track of the status of an enrollee.  Each time the status changes a new row is inserted for the enrollee.  I am trying to get the greatest status for a given enrollee for a web interface that needs sub second response time.  I have already changed the self join to use rank() and an updated index which really helped, but when I try to add where condition to find a given enrollment_process_status the query takes over a second to respond.  Any suggestions on how to improve this?

```
 CREATE TABLE "TM"."ENRL_PROCESS_STATUS" 
   (    "ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD_SK" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENRL_PROCESS_STATUS_SK" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "BACKOUT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CREATE_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "CREATE_LOGIN" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "UPDATE_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "UPDATE_LOGIN" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "ENRL_PROCESS_STATUS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ENRL_PROCESS_STATUS_SK")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ENRL_PROCESS_STATUS_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD_SK")
      REFERENCES "TM"."ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD" ("ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD_SK") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "TM"."TOM1" ON "TM"."ENRL_PROCESS_STATUS" ("ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD_SK", "CREATE_DTTM" DESC, "ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS", "PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

**SQL to identify the latest status for an enrollee**

```
SELECT enrl_enrollee_record_sk, enrollment_process_status, PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
       enrl_enrollee_record_sk, enrollment_process_status, PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD, 
       rank() over (partition by enrl_enrollee_record_sk ORDER BY CREATE_DTTM DESC) as seqnum 
    FROM TM.enrl_process_status ps
  ) A  
WHERE seqnum = 1 
AND (ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS IN (3,4,5,8) OR (ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS = 10 AND PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD in (1,3)))
```

**Without the (AND) Condition the query runs in 0 seconds with the following explain plan.**

```
Plan hash value: 2893856400

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  3420K|   169M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
|*  1 |  VIEW             |      |  3420K|   169M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT   |      |  3420K|    71M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN| TOM1 |  3420K|    71M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("SEQNUM"=1)
   2 - filter(RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY "ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD_SK" 
              ORDER BY SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_DTTM"))<=1)
```

**With the (AND) Condition the query runs over 1.2 seconds with the following explain plan.  Any thoughts on how to improve performance on this?**

```
Plan hash value: 2893856400

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  3420K|   169M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
|*  1 |  VIEW             |      |  3420K|   169M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT   |      |  3420K|    71M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN| TOM1 |  3420K|    71M|  7592   (1)| 00:01:47 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("SEQNUM"=1 AND (("ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS"=3 OR 
              "ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS"=4 OR "ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS"=5 OR 
              "ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS"=8) OR "ENROLLMENT_PROCESS_STATUS"=10 AND 
              ("PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD"=1 OR "PROCESS_STATUS_REASON_CD"=3)))
   2 - filter(RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY "ENRL_ENROLLEE_RECORD_SK" 
              ORDER BY SYS_OP_DESCEND("CREATE_DTTM"))<=1)
```

Comment: Why using `rank() over partition by` and then `seqnum = 1` and why not ROWNUM? it should improve your query performance drastically?

Comment: @Spidey - how do you propose to use ROWNUM to pick up the latest status **for each enrollee**?

Comment: Sorry, I read *SQL to identify the latest status for an enrollee* in the question so proposed that. In that case is your table design correct? You are putting all the changes in a table (like audit trail or journalling) and also using the same to identify the latest record too, without any additional info. I would suggest *1]* split it into 2 tables, 1 with the current status and other with all the status (triggers can be used to update this table), OR *2]* add an additional column which would uniquely identify the current enrollment status from the past ones and use that as a filter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We are considering table changes, but have multiple processes writing to the existing structures so don't want to have to remediate all the components.  Using triggers is not properly supported in our environment so that is not an option for us.  I was hoping for a SQL or Index change could address the performance issue.